# Spark: Provide input data as file to external executable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ramdisk

Using (py)Spark, is it possible somehow to provide input data to an executable as a file in an efficient manner?

What I currently do is:

```
listOfPaths=["path1.bin","path2.bin",...]
rdd_paths=spark_context.parallelize(listOfPaths)

def downloadAndRun(path):
   localFilePath = downloadFile(path)
   subprocess.Popen(["executable.exe", "--input", localFilePath]) 


rdd_paths.map(lambda x: downloadAndRun(x))
```

But this downloads the file from an accessible location each time to the worker node, stores it locally and then runs the application on it. This works, but is inefficient.

Since I need to run many iterations of that kind I rather would like to have the input data inside an rdd itself, which then would need to be provided to the 3rd party executable in the map stage. Ideally directly out of memory. Sadly I cannot change the executable itself, which only takes data via its --input argument.

Storing the input data inside an rdd might be possible by using a bytestream or something similar, but what about providing it to the executable?
Is this possible somehow without dumping the bytestream to a local file each time? I imagine something like a RamDisk or so for making the data a "virtual" file.

Any hints or suggestions are highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned, maybe there are much bettwe ways to do so.. any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: `"Since I need to run many iterations of that kind I rather would like to have the input data inside an rdd itself..."` do you have 1000s and mils of paths? spark will seem inefficient if the number of paths are small enough to be handled by pure python

Comment: Yes, no way to deal with it locally. Its about 400 paths, and the map stage needs to be called thousands of times with slighty changing settings. I also believe that another cluster architecture would be better suited, but thats what I have at hand.

Comment: How big are the files you are downloading each time? And what are the contents of the files? Can the file be broken down into smaller ones and applied to the external program?

Comment: About 200mb each